# Can't access nested JSON with VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vueJS and I've been trying to figure out how I can access the data within the 'figures' array. This JSON data structure is nested within another JSON that I'm accessing from an API. I've been trying to locate information online to help me figure out I can best approach this issue. I've added the information in the script tag, hoping that would help to make more understandable. Please let me know if more information is needed.

```
{
contributors: [ ],
create_dt: "2013-08-14T11:16:00.000Z",
image_attributes: null,
cited_by: "",
description: null,
figures: [
{
id: 130,
identifier: "decisionmaking-framework",
title: "Decision-Making Framework",
caption: "information on topic here",
details: null,
time_start: null,
time_end: null,
lat_max: null,
lat_min: null,
lon_max: null,
lon_min: null,
usage_limits: "more information here.",
submission_dt: null,
create_dt: "2013-08-14T11:16:00.000Z",
source_citation: "citation information",
ordinal: "3",
url: "http://www.google.com/placeholder",
_origination: null,
created_at: "2020-02-25T15:24:36.799Z",
updated_at: "2020-02-25T15:24:36.799Z",
report_id: 2040,
chapter_id: 514,
chapter_identifier: "decision-support",
report_identifier: "identifier1",
attributes: null
}
]
```

VueJS HTML Template

```
<template>
  <div id="card" class="card col-md-10 offset-1">

      <b-table :items="figures" fields="fields">
        <template>
        <h4>{{figures.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{figures.identifier}}</p>
        </template>
      </b-table>
   </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
  import RenderPage from '../../parts/modules.js'

  export default {
    name:"imageShow",
    data: function() {
      return {    
        fields: [
          {key:'identifier',label:"Identifier"}, {key:'title', label:"Title"}],
        figures: [],
        imageCount: 2,
        currentPage: 1,
        objectName: location.pathname.substring(1)
      }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Please update your formatting so the JSON is also in a code block.

Comment: @alexbea JSON formatting is updated. Thanks for taking a look this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use v-for, this is more common (Example 1).

Or also you can pass the prop for other components (Example 2).

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="loadData">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <div v-for="record in records">
      <div>
        <h2>Example 1</h2>
        <div v-for="figure in record.figures">{{ figure.title }}</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Or, Example 2</h2>
        <b-table :items="record.figures" :fields="fields"></b-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    records: [],
    fields: ['identifier', 'title'],
  }),
  methods: {
    loadData() {
      // load from API

      // For test, I load manually
      this.records.push({
        contributors: [],
        create_dt: '2013-08-14T11:16:00.000Z',
        image_attributes: null,
        cited_by: '',
        description: null,
        figures: [
          {
            id: 130,
            identifier: 'decisionmaking-framework',
            title: 'Decision-Making Framework',
            caption: 'information on topic here',
            details: null,
            time_start: null,
            time_end: null,
            lat_max: null,
            lat_min: null,
            lon_max: null,
            lon_min: null,
            usage_limits: 'more information here.',
            submission_dt: null,
            create_dt: '2013-08-14T11:16:00.000Z',
            source_citation: 'citation information',
            ordinal: '3',
            url: 'http://www.google.com/placeholder',
            _origination: null,
            created_at: '2020-02-25T15:24:36.799Z',
            updated_at: '2020-02-25T15:24:36.799Z',
            report_id: 2040,
            chapter_id: 514,
            chapter_identifier: 'decision-support',
            report_identifier: 'identifier1',
            attributes: null,
          },
        ],
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm sorry I should have gave more detail. 
So, that JSON data structure is data within another JSON data structure that is coming from an api.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)